# Extract year from date field

Tags: workflow, formula, formula-field, date

I have a custom field with date type. I want to use just the year from this date field for a calculation. I want to use to update a field value. I am unable to get only the year from the date field. I would like to get the year and subtract it by 10.

I used:
`YEAR( finish_date__c)` -> It gave an error

`YEAR( DATE(finish_date__c) )` -> Did not work this way too.

Any idea how I can just get the year and use it in formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a *date* field, it would be `YEAR(Field__c)`. However, if you're using a *date/time* field, you need to use `DATEVALUE` (e.g. `YEAR(DATEVALUE(Field__c))`. Finally, if you're trying to display it by itself, it needs to be a *number* return type. To make it *back* into a date, you'd have to use `DATE`: e.g. `DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE(Field__c)), 1, 1)`.

Comment: I have date field type. When I use it in a formula to update the text of a text field. I get an error saying - Field__c may not be used in this type of formula.

Comment: I used YEAR(Field__c)

Comment: @Rdvsm In that case, I don't think we have enough information. That error is usually related to a *specific* field that can't be used for some reason, not a generic *type* of field. Furthermore, it may even depend on exactly what's going on with the text field, etc. I'm sorry, but it sounds like you need to update your question with a lot more information. I'll delete this answer in a few minutes, because it clearly doesn't help, but you need to update your question to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Rdvsm Some fields also list as a Date, but are really a date/time. Have you tried using DATEVALUE at all?

Comment: Its a date field. I tried DATEVALUE too, but it gives the same error. The Feild__c was created as a date field. I do not see any thing different about this field. How should my questions be updated?